# How can I create a single command cli with oclif?

Tags: command-line-interface, oclif

I'm writing a CLI using oclif. I want to use it like `mycli [flags]`. But I could't found a method to create a silgle command CLI.

I have read oclif's docs, https://oclif.io/docs/flags;   There's nothing about single how to create single command CLI;

I have read this: https://github.com/oclif/oclif/issues/277, and have rename a command to index. It didn't work;

I have read this: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-create-a-single-command-node-js-cli-with-oclif-typescript-and-yarn-workspaces; But look like the `oclif siangle`  command has been dispatched;
I want to use `Mycommand.run` method, but the `--help` and `--version` flags would not work;

How can I create a single command cli?